# What is the fastest way to compute large dot products?

Tags: optimization, assembly, sse, avx, dot-product

Consider this snippet:

```
double dot(double* a, double* b, int n) {
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) sum += a[i] * b[i];
  return sum;
}
```

How can I speed it up using intrinsics or assembler?

Notes:

- You may assume newest architecture, including AVX extensions.
- `n` is few hundreds.
- dot will itself be used in a tight loop

Comment: I'm surprised your compiler doesn't do a pretty good job on a function that small already.  Can you show your current output assembly so we have a starting point?

Comment: If you're on a hyperthreaded core could you split the work between two threads?  I don't know if that would buy you much.

Comment: What compiler and what options are you using now?

Comment: Are you taking the dot product of two vectors repeatedly?  Where in the memory hierarchy are the vectors when you call `dot`?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple SSE implementation:

```
#include "pmmintrin.h"

__m128d vsum = _mm_set1_pd(0.0);
double sum = 0.0;
int k;

// process 2 elements per iteration
for (k = 0; k < n - 1; k += 2)
{
    __m128d va = _mm_loadu_pd(&a[k]);
    __m128d vb = _mm_loadu_pd(&b[k]);
    __m128d vs = _mm_mul_pd(va, vb);
    vsum = _mm_add_pd(vsum, vs);
}

// horizontal sum of 2 partial dot products
vsum = _mm_hadd_pd(vsum, vsum);
_mm_store_sd(&sum, vsum);

// clean up any remaining elements
for ( ; k < n; ++k)
{
    sum += a[k] * b[k];
}
```

Note that if you can guarantee that a and b are 16 byte aligned then you can use `_mm_load_pd` rather than `_mm_loadu_pd` which may help performance, particularly on older (pre Nehalem) CPUs.

Note also that for loops such as this where the are very few arithmetic instructions relative to the number of loads then performance may well be limited by memory bandwidth and the expected speed-up from vectorization may not be realised in practice.

---

If you want to target CPUs with AVX then it's a fairly straightforward conversion from the above SSE implementation to process 4 elements per iteration rather than 2:

```
#include "immintrin.h"

__m256d vsum = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
double sum = 0.0;
int k;

// process 4 elements per iteration
for (k = 0; k < n - 3; k += 4)
{
    __m256d va = _mm256_loadu_pd(&a[k]);
    __m256d vb = _mm256_loadu_pd(&b[k]);
    __m256d vs = _mm256_mul_pd(va, vb);
    vsum = _mm256_add_pd(vsum, vs);
}

// horizontal sum of 4 partial dot products
vsum = _mm256_hadd_pd(_mm256_permute2f128_pd(vsum, vsum, 0x20), _mm256_permute2f128_pd(vsum, vsum, 0x31));
vsum = _mm256_hadd_pd(_mm256_permute2f128_pd(vsum, vsum, 0x20), _mm256_permute2f128_pd(vsum, vsum, 0x31));
_mm256_store_sd(&sum, vsum);

// clean up any remaining elements
for ( ; k < n; ++k)
{
    sum += a[k] * b[k];
}
```

Comment: Great answer.  " if you can guarantee that a and b are 16 byte aligned then you can use _mm_load_pd rather than _mm_loadu_pd which may help performance, particularly on older (pre Nehalem) CPUs."  I would argue it's the alignment that's important even on modern CPUs (atleast up to Ivy Bridge).  The only difference since Nehalem is that load is nearly as fast as loadu on aligned memory now but load on unaligned memory is still much slower.

Comment: @raxman: true, there is still a measurable difference even on Nehalem and later CPUs, but it's a relatively small difference compared to the typically 2x hit for misaligned loads/stores on older CPUs, and for trivial operations such as the above, where memory bandwidth is likely to be the limiting factor, it may be insignificant. But yes, always try to work with 16 byte aligned wherever possible.

Comment: Doesnt hadd_pd  do horizontal add on 128-bit parts separately? Must there be a permute2f128(vsum,vsum,1) to switch up and high parts between two additions ?

Comment: why dont the engineers made any avx instruction capable of adding through all elements? For example,  _mm256_dp_ps makes separate two dot products because it is suitable for r,g,b,a or x,y,z,0 multiplications?

Comment: @huseyin: indeed - it looks like AVX is really just two SSE execution units bolted together - this is fine for most basic SIMD operations but when you have data widening/narrowing operations (pack, unpack, etc) or need to operate horizontally across a vector (horizontal add, alignr, etc) then you run into problems and you have to start permuting the vectors to make things work, which reduces overall efficiency.

Comment: Maybe avx3 fixes that. In the meantime, when I write "@Paul" it doesnt appear in the comment's head, is this a bug?.

Comment: I hope so, but I wouldn't hold your breath. As for comments, they made a change to the way @ works in comments a few months back - if you are commenting to the person who wrote the relevant question or answer then it strips out the `@user:` part of your comment, on the assumption that it's redundant - I think this is wrong, and find it a annoying, but I guess I can live with it. There is some discussion of this on http://meta.stackoverflow.com.