# my intrinsic function in getting the dot product of an int array is slower than the normal code, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, cpu, sse, intrinsics, dot-product

I'm trying to learn about ***intrinsic*** and how to properly utilize, and optimize it, I decided to implement a function to get the ***dot product*** of two arrays as a starting point to learn.

I create two functions to get the dot product of an array of integers `int`, one is coded in a normal way where you loop through every elements of the two arrays then perform multiplication with each element then add/accumulate/sum the resulting products to get the dot product.

The other uses intrinsic in a way where, I perform intrinsic operations on four elements of each array, I multiply each of them using `_mm_mullo_epi32`, then uses 2 *horizontal add* `_mm_hadd_epi32` to get the sum of the current 4 elements, after that I add it up to the dot_product, then proceed to the the next four element, then repeat until I get to the calculated limit `vec_loop`, then I calculate the other remaining elements using the normal way to avoid calculating out of the array's memory, then I compare the performance of the two.

*header file with the two types of dot product function*:

```cpp
// main.hpp
#ifndef main_hpp
#define main_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

template<typename T>
T scalar_dot(T* a, T* b, size_t len){
    T dot_product = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<len; ++i) dot_product += a[i]*b[i];
    return dot_product;
}

int sse_int_dot(int* a, int* b, size_t len){
    
    size_t vec_loop = len/4;
    size_t non_vec = len%4;
    size_t start_non_vec_i = len-non_vec;

    int dot_prod = 0;

    for(size_t i=0; i<vec_loop; ++i)
    {
        __m128i va = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(a+(i*4)));
        __m128i vb = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(b+(i*4)));
        va = _mm_mullo_epi32(va,vb);
        va = _mm_hadd_epi32(va,va);
        va = _mm_hadd_epi32(va,va);
        dot_prod += _mm_cvtsi128_si32(va);
    }

    for(size_t i=start_non_vec_i; i<len; ++i) dot_prod += a[i]*b[i];

    return dot_prod;
}

#endif
```

*cpp code to measure the time taken of each function*

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include "main.hpp"

int main()
{
    // generate random integers
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::mt19937_64 rand_engine(seed);
    std::mt19937_64 rand_engine2(seed/2);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> random_number(0,9);

    size_t LEN = 10000000;

    int* a = new int[LEN];
    int* b = new int[LEN];

    for(size_t i=0; i<LEN; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = random_number(rand_engine);
        b[i] = random_number(rand_engine2);
    }

    #ifdef SCALAR
    int dot1 = 0;
    #endif
    #ifdef VECTOR
    int dot2 = 0;
    #endif

    // timing
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    #ifdef SCALAR
    dot1 = scalar_dot(a,b,LEN);
    #endif
    #ifdef VECTOR
    dot2 = sse_int_dot(a,b,LEN);
    #endif
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start);
    std::cout<<"proccess taken "<<duration.count()<<" nanoseconds\n";

    #ifdef SCALAR
    std::cout<<"\nScalar : Dot product = "<<dot1<<"\n";
    #endif
    #ifdef VECTOR
    std::cout<<"\nVector : Dot product = "<<dot2<<"\n";
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

compilation:

- intrinsic version : `g++ main.cpp -DVECTOR -msse4.1 -o main.o`
- normal version : `g++ main.cpp -DSCALAR -msse4.1 -o main.o`

my machine:

- Architecture: x86_64
- CPU(s) : 1
- CPU core(s): 4
- Thread(s) per core: 1
- Model name: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3700  @ 1.60GHz
- L1d cache: 96 KiB
- L1i cache: 128 KiB
- L2 cache: 2 MiB
- some Flags : sse, sse2, sse4_1, sse4_2

In the `main.cpp` there are ***10000000*** elements of `int` array, when I compile the code above in my machine, it seems that the intrinsic function runs slower than the normal version, most of the time, intrinsic take around`97529675 nanoseconds` and sometimes even longer, while the normal code only takes around `87568313 nanoseconds`, here I thought that my intrinsic function should run faster if the optimization flags is off, but turns out it is indeed somehow a little bit slower.

**so my questions are:**

- why is my intrinsic function runs slower? (am I doing something wrong?)
- how can I correct my intrinsic implementation, what is the proper way?
- does the compiler auto vectorize/unroll the normal code even when the optimization flag is off
- what is the fastest way to get the dot product given the specs of my machine?

I hope someone can help, thanks

Comment: Since you compile without optimisation I assume the compiler just leaves it all as is. The biggest problem I see at a quick glance is the constant horizontal addition, just add things to a `_mm128i` and only do the horizontal addition at the end of the loop. Out of curiosity, what happens if you enable optimisation?

Comment: @Qubit if I enable optimization they both speeds up but still the intrinsic is slower, sometimes it reaches e-1 of the speed of the other

Comment: @Qubit, "just add things to a _mm128i and only do the horizontal addition at the end of the loop." so I need to allocate a temporary array? because I am not allowed to change the values of the other two arrays

Comment: Just have `_mm128i _c` set to 0 at the start (before the loop) and sum everything into that. Then at the end add up the elements of `_c` into an integer. I would expect this to perform better on pretty much all CPUs, but I might be wrong, I didn't go looking at the timings. All of this of course assumes that the loop is not 4 elements.

Comment: @Qubit "Just have ```_mm128i _c``` set to 0 at the start (before the loop) and sum everything into that. Then at the end add up the elements of ```_c``` into an integer." how would I do that? btw the array could be of any size

Comment: You do (c1,c2)=(a1,a2)*(b1,b2); s+=c1+c2 in each iteration. The suggestion is to do only (s1,s2)+=(a1,a2)*(b1,b2) in each iteration and then at then end s=s1+s2.

Comment: Don't horizontal sum inside the inner loop.  See [What is the fastest way to compute large dot products?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17011666) for an FP `double` example.  Also, you need to enable optimizations for anything to be worth benchmarking.  [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394)  Anti-optimized debug mode can slow down intrinsics even more than simple code that does more in one statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with *@Peter Cordes, @Qubit and @j6t* suggestions, I tweeked the code a little bit, I now only do multiplication inside the loop, then I moved the horizontal addition outside the loop... It managed to increase the performance of the intrinsic version from around `97529675 nanoseconds`, to around `56444187 nanoseconds` which is significantly faster than my previous implementation, with the same compilation flags and **10000000** elements of int array.

here is the new function from main.hpp

```cpp
int _sse_int_dot(int* a, int* b, size_t len){
        
    size_t vec_loop = len/4;
    size_t non_vec = len%4;
    size_t start_non_vec_i = len-non_vec;

    int dot_product;
    __m128i vdot_product = _mm_set1_epi32(0);

    for(size_t i=0; i<vec_loop; ++i)
    {
        __m128i va = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(a+(i*4)));
        __m128i vb = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(b+(i*4)));
        __m128i vc = _mm_mullo_epi32(va,vb);
        vdot_product = _mm_add_epi32(vdot_product,vc);
    }

    vdot_product = _mm_hadd_epi32(vdot_product,vdot_product);
    vdot_product = _mm_hadd_epi32(vdot_product,vdot_product);
    dot_product = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(vdot_product);

    for(size_t i=start_non_vec_i; i<len; ++i) dot_product += a[i]*b[i];

    return dot_product;
}
```

If there is more to improve with this code, please point it out, for now I'm just gonna leave it here as the answer.

Comment: Coding style: don't use `_` names for locals, it's not very distinctive with lots of other underscores in function names.  I sometimes use names like `__m128i va` for a vector related to scalar `a`.  Also don't use leading underscores in function names, that's reserved for global scope names.

Comment: `_mm_hadd_epi32` is not efficient, but it doesn't matter much because it's outside the loop.  See [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026).  But otherwise yes, that's a sensible implementation.  Benchmark with optimization enabled to see how it compares to auto-vectorized asm that your compiler generates from plain scalar C.